# Workflow for a marketing process

Tags: sql, workflow

we are looking for a solution for implementing our marketing process. I've already taken a look at a couple of solutions but can't find anything which is focused on "calling", as most of the CRMs are focused on Email marketing. We are looking for something ready, I don't want to implement it from 0 in SQL. Although some rapid dev. tool would also suite.

Our process looks as following:

We have a customer base with several attributes for each customer like city, type of product, segment and so on.It should be possible for the manager to choose the correct customers according to the attributes (e.g. all customer from city x and type y of product) and assign this customers to a marketing process.

The marketing process would look like:

- User gets a notification call customer x
- User is being asked how the call was and the user can choose from
  several categories (no interest, slight interest, wrong number, ....)
- The logic behind what happens afterwards is in the program

WORKFLOW AS A DIAGRAM:

[image]

In short:
Defining the customer range -> putting them into a process -> user gives a response in a pre defined way to the task he performed -> the process goes on

For the above described process which solution/CRM would you suggest?
I am a bit struggling with the overall amount of solutions present on the market.

Thank you!

Comment: As you are asking about a concrete business process, you should think about human-centric-workflow engines like [Imixs-Workflow](https://www.imixs.org). This is not a crm software solution, but a framework helping you to solve your business process management problem.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you're going to want a tool that has support for multiple event pushes over a time period and also real-time access to the data so that customer action flags (like picked up, unsubscribe, etc.) can be checked before each push.

There are not a lot of tools that do that. I've had customers use *MarketWide* for similar campaigns that were omni-channel. Lots of opt ins, opt outs, path changes on hand raise, etc.

MarketWide is published by Decision Software, Inc. and you can read more at [dsimarketingservices.com](https://dsimarketingservices.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty new field, although a lot of people are touting workflow solutions, but they are often more event/trigger platforms.  A true workflow engine has the ability to take a workflow definition (preferably interactively created) and apply those rule and decision trees to a particular request or job to take it from start to end.

There is an open source platform, [TACTIC](http://tactic.southpawtech.com), that I am a part of that you might want to take a look. It's very mature and robust, although it may require a bit of set-up for your specific needs.